# Solving $y'=f(x,y)$ when $f$ is a rational function $f(x,y)=\frac{y^2+2xy}{x^2y-x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Solve the initial value problem $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2+2xy^2}{x^2y-x^2},~~y(1)=1$$

My attempt: I checked whether $(x^2y-x^2)dy-(y^2+2xy)dx=0$ is exact, but it was not exact. Also the substitution $y=ux$ makes $$x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u^2+ux-u}{ux-1}$$ and stucked.

Comment: Is the numerator equal to $y^2 + 2xy$ or $y^2 + 2xy^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2+2xy^2}{x^2y-x^2}=\frac{(1+2x)y^2}{(y-1)x^2}\\
$

Your diff eq is separable.

$\int \frac {y-1}{y^2}\ dy = \int \frac {1+2x}{x^2} \ dx$

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2y-x^2)dy-(y^2+{2xy})dx=0$$
You forgot the square for $y$:
$$(x^2y-x^2)dy-(y^2+\color {red}{2xy^2})dx=0$$
$$\dfrac {(y-1)}{y^2}dy-\dfrac {(1+2x)}{x^2}dx=0$$
The differential is exact.
$$Mdx+Ndy=0$$
$$\partial_y M =\partial_x N=0$$
Note that the DE in the title and the DE in the body are different since you wrote:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{y^2+2xy}{x^2y-x^2}$$